# How can I clone / create a copy of my local meteor app?

Tags: meteor

How can I create a copy of my entire local meteor application? I was expecting a command like "meteor clone myapp" but couldn't find any documentation and simply copying the folder doesn't work.

Comment: Actually, simply copying the project folder *is* the way you do this. What do you mean it doesn't work for you? What's wrong afterwards? Perhaps something is wrong with your environment.

Comment: Sorry, your right! It was just access right issues on the folder. Hubert - this is the answer! Hopefully this might help the growing community.

Answer (score 1):

You could use git to clone the whole thing.

If you aren't familiar with git see this reference. http://gitref.org/creating/

Answer (score 0):

In windows, you can copy and paste the entire project directory and go into .meteor/local directory and delete everything in that directory except the db directory. Then start the meteor server on the new project directory, with everything deleted in the .meteor/local directory, meteor will rebuild the project without altering the logic of your application.